# How to match the data from a shp file with those contained in a dataframe?

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial, shapefile, extract

I am drawing spatial samples from a shp file. In this way:

```
pr <- readShapePoly("PuertoRico.shp")
 n <- 90
 samp.reg <- spsample(pr, n, type="regular")
```

This is what I get:

```
samp.reg
SpatialPoints:
         x1       x2
 #[1,] -66.15482 17.93279
 #[2,] -67.15842 18.02403
 #[3,] -67.06718 18.02403
 #[4,] -66.97595 18.02403
 #[5,] -66.88471 18.02403
```

And so on, till [90,]

Now, I would like to extract **those observations included in the sample just drawn** , from the dataframe containing not only the coordinates, but also the connected variable that I need to study (i.e. elevation). **Below you can see how the dataframe looks like.**

```
df <- read.csv("pr_elev_rs.csv",header=TRUE)
 head(df)
  Label         x        y elevation
1 BL192 -67.27045 18.36269         0
2 BM191 -67.26450 18.36761        30
3 BM192 -67.26490 18.36020        56
4 BM193 -67.26287 18.35222         0
5 BM194 -67.26075 18.34632         0
6 BN190 -67.25191 18.37403        10
```

I am a beginner with R and I don't know how I can do this. Thank you for the help, I really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I have undestood correctly your question.

```
 match <- df$x %in% samp.reg@coords[,1] & df$y %in% samp.reg@coords[,2]
 extract_df_row <- df[match,]
```

Is this what you need??

EDIT:
now you can subset

```
 if(nrow(extract_df_row)>0) {
  coordinates(extract_df_row) <- cbind(extract_df_row$x, extract_df_row$y)
  }else{
    cat("no coordinates matching df")
  }
```

Comment: Now it works! Thanks! However, it says that there are no rows that match the coordinates and this can't be possible.

Comment: mmm.. really strange. I substituted the first coordinates of df with the first coordinates of samp.reg in order to create a match since the piece of data provided doesn't show any match (the if ... else statement was introduced for that) and it works for me.. Are you sure there is a match in your data??

Comment: Maybe there are some issues related to the coordinates.
To check if there are any match, I just wanted to take a random x coordinate from one set and try to find the rows with the same coordinate in the other. But, when I just try to find how many rows there are with this coordinate,  x1 <- df[df$x==-65.66646,] (for instance), dim(x1) says that there are no ones. But I can see it in the data set when I tip (df)

Comment: try checking that the class of your column's coordinates `class(df$x)`.  It sounds like your column was coerced to a character or to a factor. But it's hard to say without the complete dataset.

Comment: class(df$x)  " numeric" 

when I search for a row with a given coord, it says this :" <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)"

Comment: If you can share an exemple (e.g. the piece of dataset where the problem takes place)  I can try to help, otherwise this trial and error could take days :). Consider to edit this thread or eventually post a new question.

Comment: 9093 IZ209 -65.66790 18.20855         0  this is the last column that i can see, by tipping " df".  As you can see, the third one is df$x, the fourth df$y, and the fitfh is the value of the variable that I am studying. I have tried to extract from it all the rows with the coordinate - 65.66790, in this way: x1 <- df$x=="-65.66790" , but if then I do this : dim(x1) it gives "NULL". I tried it out to check what is wrong with this dataset, since the matching function (that you wrote) didn't give any result.

Comment: you should be able to subset it with df[df$x==-65.66790,]. If not consider to remove everything from environment typing `rm(list=ls())` restart your R session and reimport everything. I can't do more than this...

Comment: I met my professor and we that there are some problems with the dataset ! Anyway, thank you for your help!